# SSH from OS X to Cent OS through a Cent OS hop

Tags: macos, ssh, centos

**My goal is, if possible, to connect through**

> $ ssh end-host

Because I need an ssh connection to tunnel to for a connection to mysql, which end-point can make but hop-host can not.

## TL; DR

I'm actually looking at a way to have `.ssh/config` allowing me to do

> ssh end-host

When behind the scene it would do

> ssh -t hop-host ssh end-host

---

When the action behind the scene is

```
Macbook -> hop-user@hop-host (id_rsa authentication) -> end-host-user@end-host (id_rsa authentication)
```

Where end-host, end-host-user and identity file to end host are know and defined in `/home/hop-user/.ssh/config` on the hop-host.

**Macbook `~/.ssh/config`**

```
Host hop-host
    User hop-user
    Hostname valid.tested.public.ip.address.to.hop.host
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host end-host
    HostName end-point-hostname-as-defined-on-hop-host
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p hop-host
```

**Hop host Cent OS `~/.ssh/config` for hop-user**

```
Host end-point-hostname-as-defined-on-hop-host
    HostName valid.tested.internal.ip.address.to.end.host
    User end-host-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/endhost
```

**Limitation to be aware of** : I cannot change any config on hop/end hosts and I don't have `nc` installed on those.

**Current problem with the given configuration**

> $ ssh end-host
>   channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited:
>   open failed ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

**Thing that works** :

> $ ssh -t hop-host ssh end-point-hostname-as-defined-on-hop-host

correctly prompt me end-host-bash$ and allows me to do anything I want from there

**Things that does not work or works partially and that I tried**

1) Changing Macbook `~/.ssh/config` end-host config for HostName and User

```
Host end-host
    HostName valid.tested.internal.ip.address.to.end.host
    User end-host-user
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p hop-host
```

> $ ssh end-host
>   end-host-user@valid.tested.internal.ip.address.to.end.host's password:

Which I obviously don't have. And I guess it is because hop-host's `.ssh/config` is not red.

2) Changing Macbook `~/.ssh/config` end-host config for ProxyCommand

```
Host end-host
    ProxyCommand ssh -t hop-host ssh end-point-hostname-as-defined-on-hop-host
```

> $ ssh end-host
>   Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
>   Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
>   : command not found2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
>   ls
>   ^CKilled by signal 2.

bash returns me a possibility to type in but there is no display of my commands.
I understand that is because there is a call to `-o ProxyCommand="the command in .ssh/config in the right host"` behind the scene but I may be lacking to understand how it actually works.